# What are power amplifiers?

Tags: analog, power-electronics

What is a power amplifier? What is the difference between power amplifier and simple amplifier? As both are amplifying the signal what's the difference?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. -1

Answer (score 2):

A power amplifier, as the name implies, is not just intended to amplify a signal, but to also have that signal provide significant power.  A "preamp" might take a 1 mV microphone signal and make a 1 V "line" signal.  It provides substantial voltage gain, but is not a power amplifier.  Another amp might take that 1 V signal and make a 10 V signal that can drive a 8 Ω loudspeaker load.  That is only a voltage gain of 10, but that signal has to be able to provide close to 15 W of power, making that a "power" amp.  There are no fixed definitions, but the classification "power amp" is to give you a idea of intended use and application.

Answer (score 2):

As Olin rightly points out, you could have found the answer on Wikipedia.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier#Power_amplifier):

> The term power amplifier is a relative term with respect to the amount of power delivered to the load and/or sourced by the supply circuit. In general a power amplifier is designated as the last amplifier in a transmission chain (the output stage) and is the amplifier stage that typically requires most attention to power efficiency.

So a power amplifier supplies power to drive the final load, while other amplifiers are more likely to drive higher-impedance inputs. So you might have a chain of amplifiers, each one modifying the signal in some fashion to feed the next one. Only the last one, the power amplifier, would drive the load (say, a speaker).

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Wikipedia section on power amplifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier#Power_amplifier) sums it up well with the following:

> The term power amplifier is a relative term with respect to the amount
>   of power delivered to the load and/or sourced by the supply circuit.
>   In general a power amplifier is designated as the last amplifier in a
>   transmission chain (the output stage) and is the amplifier stage that
>   typically requires most attention to power efficiency.

There's really not a definitive answer in terms of absolute power, for example a power amplifier that drives headphones may fall into the tens of milliwatts region, while something like an FM broadcasting transmitter will often be thousands of watts.

In the case of something like a transmitter you may see terms like preamplifier that takes a small level like a microphone input up to a higher level for other amplifiers (sometimes called gain blocks) that gets it up to a level suitable for input to the final stage, or power amplifier.

But the terms can be somewhat fuzzy and they are all just amplifier stages that have varying amounts of gain and potential power output to deliver the end result needed, while trying to minimize the amount of noise introduced along the way.

Answer (score 1):

All amplifiers amplify something and that something is power. However, the name "power amplifier" is usually reserved for the type of amplifier that might get a little warm when driving a load. These loads are speakers, antennas, motors, displays etc..

Comment: All amplifiers need not represent a net power increase between input and output.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh i'm always keen to learn so please give details

Comment: The project I am currently struggling with is in effect a [Charge Amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_amplifier), that integrates Coulombic charge and outputs a voltage, with no actual power relationship between input and output, amplification or attenuation - since there is a transformation going on. A transconductance amplifier is another such. I'm sure you can now find several other examples.

Comment: A amplifier is meant to increase some parameter of a signal, usually to scale it up linearly.  However, that parameter is not necessarily power.  Often the point is to amplify voltage.  Often that also means a power increase, but not necessarily, depending on the impedances.  A good example is a opamp circuit that amplifies the 1 Ohm output of a current transformer by 3, then presents a 10 kOhm signal to a A/D input.  You get 9x power gain from the voltage, but lose 10 k from impedance, for a net power loss of 1100x.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, although this has been quite some time ago I hope Olin comes back and sees this. I a completely lost with your statement above - let alone where you computes figures are derived from. The idea of driving a signal characterized by impedance is confusing to me. Where may I find documentation on this subject? I suppose to me, the characteristics of a signal are voltage/current .. unless perhaps you are saying V/I (=10,000) signal - defining it in this way?